# Unity APK crashes after the "Made with Unity" splash screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, apk, logcat

Hey guys the apk is crashing AFTER the unity splash screen. I genuinely have no idea what to do(search didn't result in much too). But I do suspect that it might be because of unity ads, however in editor it works correctly.
Logcat log shows the following:

```
2023/02/07 19:33:26.612 24885 24909 Error CRASH pid: 24885, tid: 24909, name: UnityMain  >>> com.RainingCycles.DMT <<<
2023/02/07 19:33:26.612 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #00 pc 000000000017a060  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityAdsSettings_Get_Custom_PropTestMode()+44) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #04 pc 0000000000412fb0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+164) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #05 pc 0000000000426e74  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+156) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #06 pc 0000000000429b98  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::InvokeChecked(ScriptingExceptionPtr*)+52) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #07 pc 0000000000474148  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (SerializableManagedRef::CallMethod(Object&, ScriptingMethodPtr)+84) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #08 pc 0000000000437dc0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::CallAwake()+124) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #09 pc 00000000004381cc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::AddToManager()+216) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #10 pc 0000000000437d28  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::AwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode)+648) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #11 pc 0000000000476d64  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokePersistentManagerAwake(AwakeFromLoadQueue::Item*, unsigned int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)+328) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #12 pc 0000000000476b7c  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)+136) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #13 pc 0000000000476ad8  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(ErrorsAndWarningsCapture*, bool)+32) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #14 pc 00000000002caec0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompleteAwakeSequence()+220) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #15 pc 00000000002cb1a8  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompletePreloadManagerLoadScene()+24) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #16 pc 00000000002caa88  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread()+652) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #17 pc 00000000002cab6c  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompleteLoadFirstScene()+4) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #18 pc 00000000002ca6a4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread()+188) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #19 pc 00000000002cbbfc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)+276) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #20 pc 00000000002cc2d4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete()+148) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #21 pc 00000000004ba7bc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+348) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:26.613 24885 24909 Error CRASH       #22 pc 00000000004ed5d4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+72) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: UnityMain
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime pid: 24885, tid: 24909, name: UnityMain  >>> com.RainingCycles.DMT <<<
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #00 pc 000000000017a060  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityAdsSettings_Get_Custom_PropTestMode()+44) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #04 pc 0000000000412fb0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+164) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #05 pc 0000000000426e74  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)+156) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #06 pc 0000000000429b98  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (ScriptingInvocation::InvokeChecked(ScriptingExceptionPtr*)+52) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #07 pc 0000000000474148  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (SerializableManagedRef::CallMethod(Object&, ScriptingMethodPtr)+84) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #08 pc 0000000000437dc0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::CallAwake()+124) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #09 pc 00000000004381cc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::AddToManager()+216) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #10 pc 0000000000437d28  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (MonoBehaviour::AwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode)+648) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #11 pc 0000000000476d64  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokePersistentManagerAwake(AwakeFromLoadQueue::Item*, unsigned int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)+328) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #12 pc 0000000000476b7c  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)+136) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #13 pc 0000000000476ad8  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(ErrorsAndWarningsCapture*, bool)+32) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #14 pc 00000000002caec0  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompleteAwakeSequence()+220) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #15 pc 00000000002cb1a8  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompletePreloadManagerLoadScene()+24) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #16 pc 00000000002caa88  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread()+652) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #17 pc 00000000002cab6c  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::CompleteLoadFirstScene()+4) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #18 pc 00000000002ca6a4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread()+188) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #19 pc 00000000002cbbfc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)+276) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #20 pc 00000000002cc2d4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete()+148) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #21 pc 00000000004ba7bc  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+348) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.142 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime       #22 pc 00000000004ed5d4  /data/app/~~X5b4cYCjxWAM8vvZK_lbwg==/com.RainingCycles.DMT-VS4JOWE3fAH1Rn8z1lnqbA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+72) (BuildId: 0d8aeea21f4d601bdab35989a90d0b31f9472a21)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.UnityAdsSettings_Get_Custom_PropTestMode()(UnityAdsSettings_Get_Custom_PropTestMode:44)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.scripting_method_invoke(ScriptingMethodPtr, ScriptingObjectPtr, ScriptingArguments&, ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)(scripting_method_invoke:164)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.ScriptingInvocation::Invoke(ScriptingExceptionPtr*, bool)(Invoke:156)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.ScriptingInvocation::InvokeChecked(ScriptingExceptionPtr*)(InvokeChecked:52)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.SerializableManagedRef::CallMethod(Object&, ScriptingMethodPtr)(CallMethod:84)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.MonoBehaviour::CallAwake()(CallAwake:124)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.MonoBehaviour::AddToManager()(AddToManager:216)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.MonoBehaviour::AwakeFromLoad(AwakeFromLoadMode)(AwakeFromLoad:648)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.AwakeFromLoadQueue::InvokePersistentManagerAwake(AwakeFromLoadQueue::Item*, unsigned int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)(InvokePersistentManagerAwake:328)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(int, AwakeFromLoadMode, bool)(PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad:136)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.AwakeFromLoadQueue::PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad(ErrorsAndWarningsCapture*, bool)(PersistentManagerAwakeFromLoad:32)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.LoadSceneOperation::CompleteAwakeSequence()(CompleteAwakeSequence:220)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.LoadSceneOperation::CompletePreloadManagerLoadScene()(CompletePreloadManagerLoadScene:24)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.LoadSceneOperation::PlayerLoadSceneFromThread()(PlayerLoadSceneFromThread:652)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.LoadSceneOperation::CompleteLoadFirstScene()(CompleteLoadFirstScene:4)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.LoadSceneOperation::IntegrateMainThread()(IntegrateMainThread:188)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)(UpdatePreloadingSingleStep:276)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.PreloadManager::WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete()(WaitForAllAsyncOperationsToComplete:148)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.UnityPlayerLoop()(UnityPlayerLoop:348)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.143 24885 24909 Error AndroidRuntime    at libunity.nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)(nativeRender:72)
2023/02/07 19:33:27.158 1195 2302 Warn ActivityTaskManager   Force finishing activity com.RainingCycles.DMT/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
```

I tried these options: I removed the automatic graphics API and assigned Vulcan and OPENGLES3, Colorspace is gamma, Minimum API level is 22 and max is 33. I don't have google plugin installed. Yet. Scripting backend: IL2CPP. No custom manifests or templates, minify is off, split application binary is off too. Additional player settings pictures are [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-apk-crash-libunity-so.1396735/#post-8787616). Unity version: 2021.3.15f1

Comment: First error says ads. Id say youre right its the ads.

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for the answer. Deleting unity ads might be my last resort

Comment: Okay guys the issue might be that I have unity ads without mediation. I will answer it if it's true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer truly lied in ads. I forgot to turn it on in project settings+I resolved issues by using Google play plugin. Cheers